# Best way to make a formula with indeterminate number of variables

Tags: r

I have lots of data. I would like to make a formula to use in glm

Data is in a vector like this:

{a1,a2,b1,b2,...}

and I would like to make a formula like this:

Identity ~ a1:a2 + b1:b2 + ...

any suggestions for something quick and easy?

Comment: Example data would be helpful (See `?dput`). For instance, you say your data are in a vector, suggesting `a1` is a single number. But then the formula notation suggests `a1` is a whole vector, itself.

Comment: This has been asked here for [million of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+formula). Just simply `paste()` up all the formula as text and then convert it to formula using `as.formula`.

Comment: Thanks guys I ended up going with paste and figured out how to use its separator parameters to get what I wanted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting coefficient names to a formula in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281000/converting-coefficient-names-to-a-formula-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.  Providing example data would make it easier.  Is the following similar to what you are after?

```
## Create example data
variables <- c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2")
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(70), ncol = 7))
names(dat) <- c("Identity", variables)

## Create formula
formula <- paste(variables[grep("1$", variables)], variables[grep("2$", variables)], sep = ":", collapse = " + ")
formula <- paste("Identity ~ ", formula, sep = "")

## Run model
glm1 <- glm(formula = formula, data = dat)
summary(glm1)
```

Above, the formula is created with `paste()`, and the `sep` and `collapse` arguments are used to make everything come together with the appropriate `:` and `+`.